# ActionScript 3.0 P2P Connection WITHOUT encryption?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, encryption, p2p, adobe-cirrus

Is there any way to create a direct data connection between two flash clients without the use of Cirrus?

I'm asking because I create a multiplayer iPhone game with flash which currently uses Cirrus for all online multiplayer data. now I read that, if your iPhone app uses encryption (which cirrus does) you need to go through a long encryption export approval process by the U.S government. I want to avoid this, so now i'm looking for another method to exchange data directly between clients without having to route all traffic through my server.

Comment: Flash?->iPhone?->When? Steve Jobs wont allow Flash on an iPhone. So how is your game "currently" running on an iPhone.

Comment: you can create iOS apps with flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With AIR you have ServerSocket [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) for p2p connections

Comment: thank you - ServerSocket is unfortunately not supported on mobile devices :( is there any other way to do it?